# Store Temporary Sensitive Data In Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails app but i'm having trouble implementing a solution for storing temporary data and automatically clearing it when the user sees it. I thought about using flash but that only works when the user visits via the next request. Im looking for something that will let the user browse the site and view other things but once they get to the page such as /example/, they see the temporary sensitive data, then next time they reload that page  or go somewhere else and come back its permanently gone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis will be fastest and simplest solution (but not such simple as flash notices). Redis have built in `lpop` method to get something from list and remove it after that. I think you will not find good solution which will not require some setup (e.g. Redis installation)

Comment: Thank you for this, is redis also secure for storing an unhashed password temporarily?

Comment: I think no. Nothing is secure to store unhashed password (neither flash notices, logs, database, etc).